# MySQL | Разница в запросе удаление

Tags: mysql

В чем разница между этими запросами? Результат один и тот же.

**Вариант 1:**

```
DELETE FROM `users` WHERE id = 1;
```

**Вариант 2:**

```
DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `users` . id = 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В таком примере нет разницы. Явно указывать таблицу надо, если у тебя их в запросе несколько и у них есть поле с одинаковым названием (id)

```
DELETE FROM users
JOIN street ON user.street_id = street.id
WHERE street.id=N
```

Comment: *Явно указывать таблицу надо, если у тебя их в запросе несколько и у них есть поле с одинаковым названием (id)* В общем случае - всегда, если используется более одной таблицы. Например, в коррелированном подзапросе поле внешней таблицы надо обязательно алиасить - даже если в структуре внутренней таблицы такого поля нет.